# Trying to duplicate file tree as in Files app

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui, nsfilemanager

I am trying to get to the file system directory similar to the Files app on iOS or the Finder on MacOS and don't seem to be getting the expected results.

- On the iOS simulator I get the MacOS directory instead of the iOS directory, but the results are basically what I might expect, just the wrong file system.
- On an iOS device, I just get the "Users" directory but it isn't identified as a directory.
- On the MacOS Catalyst simulator the Users directory is correctly identified, but trying to get its contents comes up empty.
- On all three platforms I also get a second url of file:///Network/Users/ which is not identified as a directory.

So, I have several questions. (a) Is my isDirectory function the correct way to detect if something is a directory? (b) Is there a better way of handling detection of a hidden file than what I've done in isHidden? (c) Is it incorrect to assume that directories on iOS are similar to MacOS? (d) I believe I've got access permission issues that are causing me not to be able to retrieve the contents of folders, maybe something else, not sure. How do I get access to all files that I can see in Finder/Files? (e) The Link function documentation states that it should open the referenced file in the appropriate app for the operating system, but it does nothing.

**This is a sample app to demonstrate the issues I am encountering.**

Thanks for any help/insights you might provide.

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import FileProvider

struct FileBrowser: View
{
    @State var files:[URL]
    
    init()
    {
        _files = State(initialValue: FileManager.default.urls(for: .userDirectory, in: .allDomainsMask).sorted(by: { $0.lastPathComponent < $1.lastPathComponent }))
    }
    
    init(dir: URL)
    {
        _files = State(initialValue: getFiles(dir: dir))
    }
    
    var body: some View
    {
        List
        {
            ForEach(files, id:\.self)
            {
                url in
                if !isHidden(url: url)
                {
                    if isDirectory(url)
                    {
                        NavigationLink(destination: FileBrowser(dir: url))
                        {
                            Text(url.lastPathComponent)
                        }
                    } else
                    {
                        Link(url.lastPathComponent, destination: url)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Files")
    }
}

func isDirectory(_ url: URL) -> Bool
{
    var isDirectory: ObjCBool = ObjCBool((0 != 0))
    
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path, isDirectory: &isDirectory)
    {
        return isDirectory.boolValue
    } else
    {
        return false
    }
}

func isHidden(url: URL) -> Bool
{
    return url.lastPathComponent.starts(with: ".")
}

func getFiles(dir: URL) -> [URL]
{
    do
    {
        return try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: dir, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil).sorted(by: { $0.lastPathComponent < $1.lastPathComponent })
    }
    catch
    {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return []
    }
}
```

Comment: Too many questions to be addressed. Yes, you're going to run into permissions issues -- especially on iOS -- you can't arbitrarily list the contents of anything except the app-owned directories.

Comment: Your `isDirectory` and `isHidden` functions are the same.  It isn't safe to simply parse the URLs.  Files that start with `.` are hidden from `ls` by convention, but they aren't actually "hidden" files in terms of the hidden attribute.  You need to use `FileManager` to examine the file properties

Comment: And, as @jnpdx says, this is a pretty pointless exercise on iOS; your app can only see its own sandbox.

Comment: I don't believe that is true. Apple's documentation states -- To give other apps access to the files in your Documents directory, just set the proper keys in your app’s Info.plist file. You can either set the UISupportsDocumentBrowser key (for document browser-based apps), or set both the UIFileSharingEnabled and LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace keys.
These keys enable other apps to open and edit the contents of your Documents directory in place. Your files also appear in both the Files app and the document browser.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this isn't exactly answering any of my questions, it is a solution to the problem(s) I was facing. One can indeed browse and open/edit any document that is "visible" in Files/Finder by using UIDocumentPickerController.

I found a post that explains how to do what I was after.

https://capps.tech/blog/read-files-with-documentpicker-in-swiftui